# Dynamic use of Workspace Mechanic in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Can Workspace Mechanic be configured to load certain rules only if a given plugin or feature is installed?

For example, we have both Java and C++ developers. As it stands today, you get the option to follow both Java AND C++ guidelines in the workspace popup. Can Workspace Mechanic check if JDT and/or CDT are installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think Workspace Mechnanic supports this out of the box. However, as it provides [extension points](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/source/browse/#git%2Fplugins%2Fcom.google.eclipse.mechanic%2Fschema), you may be able to build your own plugin to reach your goal. I did it once, but had to use a fragment to access internal capabilities not to reinvent the wheel.